# Stopping the loader animation when it actually loads

Tags: javascript, html, css

so I copied a loader animation, loader CSS and everything from this site I found and the problem I have now with it, is that the animation won't stop. Logically, I need it to stop when the site loads. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways but you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  
 $("...").fadeOut(3000,function(){
  $("...").remove();
 })
})
```

Or this:

```
jQuery(window).load(function () {
    $("...").fadeOut(3000,function(){
     $("...").remove();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont like to use jQuery
http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#ready

```js
function ready(fn) {
  if (document.readyState != 'loading') {
    fn();
  } else if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
  } else {
    document.attachEvent('onreadystatechange', function() {
      if (document.readyState != 'loading')
        fn();
    });
  }
}

// test
window.ready(function() {
    alert('remove loader now');
});
```